# PHP - Make some fields anonymous

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using PHP. I have somes forms that will be used to votes, surveys, etc. I'd like to know how can i make the fields like Name, second name anonymous when the form is submited. The votes, survey, are not all anonymous, it should be an option for the admin to define if the form is anonymous or not.
Could you please explain me how can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it's ever possible to make a name anonymous.

Comment: How about not asking for it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply not store the data in your database if you want it to be anonymous? Or if you want it to *appear* anonymous, just don't output the results to your users.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP crypt() to hash your variables so if they ever need to be checked again you can just match up the salts. For more info check out the examples on:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php